# Prevent a Fixed Positioned Background from Jumping to the Top of a Page on a Click Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have developed an image/lightbox viewer for multiple images on a page. When the viewer is opened, it adds a `.no-scroll` class to the `<body>` tag. Aside from everything else functioning properly, I'm trying to figure out why the `.no-scroll` class jumps to the top of the page each time it is prompted with a .click() event.

I've read that this may have something to do with `position: fixed;` being applied, but since I need the position to be fixed in this case, there doesn't appear to be a ton of workarounds. I've even tried applying `position: absolute;` instead, but this didn't produce the result I wanted because it didn't prevent the body background from vertically scrolling on mobile devices, (whereas `position: fixed;` was able to).

Here's a snippet that should further exemplify the issue at hand:

```js
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $('body').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').addClass("target");
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').removeClass("target");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FFEo8jRHyI8/TtEKfbM9UTI/AAAAAAAAADk/Nj1P4BnDyro/s1600/Grass+00+seamless.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 150px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox.target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox.target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 4 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://i2.wp.com/lfisdelhi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Sunflower-icon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 5 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://icongal.com/gallery/image/203372/birthday_flower_love_valentine_yellow_rose.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Controls -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remove the `position: fixed;`

```js
var $scrollTop = 0;
$('.pic > img').click(function () {
    var $body = $('body');
    $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $body.css('position', 'fixed');
    $body.css('top', '-' + $scrollTop + 'px');
    $body.css('background-position', '0 -' + $scrollTop + 'px');
    var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
    $body.find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
    $body.addClass('no-scroll');
    $('#view').addClass("target");
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function () {
    var $body = $('body');
    $body.css('position', '');
    $body.css('background-position', '');
    $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop($scrollTop);
    $body.removeClass('no-scroll');
    $('#view').removeClass("target");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FFEo8jRHyI8/TtEKfbM9UTI/AAAAAAAAADk/Nj1P4BnDyro/s1600/Grass+00+seamless.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

img {
    width: 150px
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
}

.container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: -5;
    opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: -50px;
    right: -3px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    width: 2px;
    left: 14px;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 2px;
    top: 14px;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox.target {
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox.target img {
    opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.target ~ #customlightbox-controls {
    top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.target ~ #customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
    width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.target ~ #customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
    height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 4 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://i2.wp.com/lfisdelhi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Sunflower-icon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 5 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://www.iconexperience.com/_img/v_collection_png/256x256/shadow/flower_blue.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Controls -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate"></a>
</div>
```

### **EDIT**

Above is an update of the snippet, I hope it finally helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and information resources included. Though, your solution may have solved a few things, there is still the issue of the `<body>` background area being scrollable when the lightbox viewer is opened on a mobile browser, such as Safari. The only solution I've found to preventing this so far was applying `position: fixed;` to the `body.no-scroll` class, but from your answer, you are not advising that as a possibility. Maybe there's another way?

Comment: Ok, so I understand that if I remove `position: fixed;` it will work, but then by doing that it will affect the `<body>` behavior on a mobile browser, enabling  the background to be scrolled when the lightbox window active, which I do not want...

Comment: @nrweb it seem I forgot the part of the background on mobile. Could you edit your answer with a snippet more according to your problem?, for taking it as a base to figure out a solution. I mean, you have to include a background that will be affected in mobile.

Comment: Do you mean to format the snippet to act more responsively?

Comment: I mean put a background to the `body`, that got the issue you are getting.

Comment: Ok, I have just added a background image to my original snippet, should display in mobile. Let me know if you need me to implement, or modify anything else.

Comment: Review again the snippet at my answer.

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you so much for helping, this completely resolved the issues I was having!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to remove the position fixed from `body.no-scroll`. Applying position fixed to an element removes it from the document flow. The element will then be position relative to the viewport and because the body basically defines the viewport there is nothing relative to it that has a scroll so the browser defaults to the top of the page.

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, it is late here. This definition of posititon:fixed on mozilla might help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

EDITED: Edited because @Yulio Aleman Jimenez showed that `.lb-animate` didn't need `position:fixed` instead, which is what I thought.

```js
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $('body').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').addClass("target");
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').removeClass("target");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 150px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox.target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox.target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 4 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://i2.wp.com/lfisdelhi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Sunflower-icon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 5 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://www.iconexperience.com/_img/v_collection_png/256x256/shadow/flower_blue.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Controls -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer, but it still didn't fully resolve the issue. See my comment on @Yulio's answer above, where I describe the remaining issue more in depth.