# Closing a Lightbox Window by Clicking on the Background Area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have developed a lightbox feature which I am trying to figure out how to close the lightbox preview window by clicking on the background area behind the image displayed, (while keeping the image unaffected).

Here's a demo snippet. There's a button toggle control at the upper, right-hand corner to close the lightbox window, but I would like to be able to close the window by clicking on the background area surrounding the image as well. Any input?

**UPDATE: The Solution**

Finally got this working, thanks to [Marouen Mhiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5595389/marouen-mhiri). Updated my original snippet here:

```js
var $scrollTop = 0;
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var $body = $('body');
  $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $body.css('position', 'fixed');
  $body.css('top', '-' + $scrollTop + 'px');
  $body.css('background-position', '0 -' + $scrollTop + 'px');
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $body.find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  $body.addClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').addClass("target");
});

$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function() {
  var $body = $('body');
  $body.css('position', '');
  $body.css('background-position', '');
  $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop($scrollTop);
  $body.removeClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').removeClass("target");
});

$('.customlightbox-imgwrap').on('click', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass('imgsrc')){
   var $body = $('body');
   $body.css('position', '');
   $body.css('background-position', '');
   $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop($scrollTop);
   $body.removeClass('no-scroll');
   $('#view').removeClass("target");
  } 
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #58d68d;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 150px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox.target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox.target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 4 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://i2.wp.com/lfisdelhi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Sunflower-icon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 5 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://icongal.com/gallery/image/203372/birthday_flower_love_valentine_yellow_rose.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Controls -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate"></a>
</div>
```

This question stems from a previous question, answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244860/prevent-a-fixed-positioned-background-from-jumping-to-the-top-of-a-page-on-a-cli).

Comment: why don't you use $('.customlightbox-imgwrap') instead of $('#customlightbox-controls')? I don't really understand the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the click event of the div containing the lightbox and fire the event only if the clicked area doesn't contain the image:

```
$('.customlightbox-imgwrap').on('click', function(e) {
   if(!$(e.target).hasClass('imgsrc')){ // check if target is not the image displayed
     var $body = $('body');
     $body.css('position', '');
     $body.css('background-position', '');
     $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop($scrollTop);
     $body.removeClass('no-scroll');
     $('#view').removeClass("target");
   } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I keep the image in the preview window unaffected by the click that closes the window?

Comment: you mean you don't want to close the layer when you click on the image?

Answer (score 0):

### Hiding the lightbox by clicking on the background

It is possible by adding *#view* to the following code.

#### Before

```
$('#customlightbox-controls').on('click', function()
```

#### After

```
$('#customlightbox-controls, #view').on('click', function()
```

```js
var $scrollTop = 0;
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var $body = $('body');
  $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  $body.css('position', 'fixed');
  $body.css('top', '-' + $scrollTop + 'px');
  $body.css('background-position', '0 -' + $scrollTop + 'px');
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $body.find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  $body.addClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').addClass("target");
});

$('#customlightbox-controls, #view').on('click', function() {
  var $body = $('body');
  $body.css('position', '');
  $body.css('background-position', '');
  $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop($scrollTop);
  $body.removeClass('no-scroll');
  $('#view').removeClass("target");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #58d68d;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  width: 150px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox.target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox.target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox.target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 4 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://i2.wp.com/lfisdelhi.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Sunflower-icon.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 5 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://icongal.com/gallery/image/203372/birthday_flower_love_valentine_yellow_rose.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Controls -->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, though it does resolve the background area functionality, I would like for the image being previewed in the lightbox window to not be included in the elements that close the window.